# iteration of set via JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json, jax-rs

I have a list of `Appuser.java` which is contains a set of `Role.java`.

When I am producing a response via REST using:

```
@produce@Produces(value="application/json")
```

It only converts `AppUsers` parameters not a set.

I have tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/nhp/rest/evaluator/fetchEvaluators',
    success : function(data) {

        for(var a=0;a<data.length;a++){
            $("#userData").append('<tr><td>'+data[a].employeeId+'</td><td>'+data[a].name+'</td><td>'+data[a].lastName+'</td><td>'+data[a].role+'</td></tr>');
        }

    },
});
```

I want `role.roleName` but it is not working.

Comment: What is the actual data being returned?

Comment: Can you show the code for the web service method that you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

First, can you show your json ?

Then, if i were you i would use the function each from jquery.

```
$(data).each(function(i, elt){
    $("#userData").append('<tr><td>' + elt.employeeId + '</td><td>' + elt.name + '</td><td>' + elt.lastName + '</td><td>' + elt.role + '</td></tr>');    
})
```

Hope it helps!